# What does it mean that "the central limit theorem does not hold far away from the peak"?

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

So I know nothing about large deviations theory, and I'm reading some [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07571.pdf). They claim that:

> The CLT does not hold far away from the peak

I am not sure how to parse this statement. There are many statements of the CLT but here is the one I know:

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2<\infty$. Then the following sum:
>
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n X_n$$
>
> converges in distribution as $n\to\infty$ to $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Why do the notes say that central limit theorem doesn't hold away from $0$? There's nothing in the central limit theorem that says "only for some interval around $0$". Does it just mean that the convergence rate is very slow and impractical?

Comment: It seems the point that they're trying to make is that while the unconditional distribution (or perhaps even conditional on events with probability close to $1$) of the weighted sum is "close" to normal, the distribution conditional on low-probability events is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, essentially it means that if you are far away from the mean (which in this case is 0), the 'approxmation' that the sum random variable (call it r.v. $Y$) you have is like the normal distribution becomes really bad.

If you want to understand this, just take some simple example. Let $n=10$ and say you have uniform random variables in range $[0,1]$. If you calculate something like $P(10000<Y<1000000)$ twice, once with the real distribution of $Y$ and another time with the normal 'approximation', you shall see that the difference is huge! Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, in the first case you get $0$ in the second you get "not $0$". But if you let $n$ get big enough, the approximation gets a lot better, right? It's just a bad approximation for lower $n$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. As n is larger, your approximation is better and better.